# Can called code determine if it's being called with "await" vs ".wait()"

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, signalr, async-await

I had a .NET SignalR client with the following code:

```
   IHubProxy proxy = objConnection.CreateHubProxy("stockTicker");
   objConnection.Start().Wait();
   Console.WriteLine(objConnection.ConnectionId);
```

The issue is that the client hung after 30 seconds, requiring a reconnect.  The solution was to change the Wait method:

```
   IHubProxy proxy = objConnection.CreateHubProxy("stockTicker");
   await objConnection.Start();
   Console.WriteLine(objConnection.ConnectionId);
```

I can't see a reason for people to call "Wait" on SignalR, or in a few other cases.  Is there a way for called code (`Start()` in this example) to know the manner in which it's invoked?

The idea is that for use cases that shouldn't be `Waited()`, an exception can be thrown.

Comment: I would write a code that would work in both cases instead of detecting how it is called...

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a custom awaitable (i.e. not `Task`), but I don't think that's a reasonable solution here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. However, I expect static analysis tools like ReSharper will be able to warn on these kinds of conditions in the near future. You could even write your own warning, e.g., using Roslyn or a Re# plugin.

The reason this isn't possible is because the code:

```
objConnection.Start().Wait();
```

is the same as:

```
var task = objConnection.Start();
task.Wait();
```

and the code:

```
await objConnection.Start();
```

is the same as:

```
var task = objConnection.Start();
await task;
```

So there's clearly no (sane) way for `Start` to know what the code will do *after* it's called.